# Error “Could not transfer metadata” jenkins Maven deploy artifacts

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, nexus

I just launched a job on Jenkins for deploy the artifacts in nexus repository but I got the message below.

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
>   (default-deploy) on project maven-simple: Failed to retrieve remote
>   metadata
>   com.github.jitpack:maven-simple:0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could
>   not transfer metadata
>   com.github.jitpack:maven-simple:0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>   from/to my-snapshots
>   (http://localhost:8181/repository/maven-snapshots/): Connect to
>   localhost:8181 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
>   (Connection refused) -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have installed Nexus on your local Computer? is the pot correect? What is Happening if you call the URL in a browser?

Comment: Please add more Details to your question: What did you try?

Comment: hello,

this is my pom.xml

https://github.com/Ismail-Elyaakouby/pipeline3/blob/master/pomold.xml

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a local-repo (nexus? other?) on your localhost (localhost:8181). And you did not upload your SNAPSHOT artifact of com.github.jitpack:maven-simple:0.2-SNAPSHOT to it.

You should build (maven build) that project (com.github.jitpack:maven-simple:0.2-SNAPSHOT), so maven will find it in your repo when you build your own project.

In these kind of questions, you can help others to help you if you paste here you pom.xml and your settings.xml

Comment: thank you @OhadR  for your answer

yes i use a local-repo

Comment: as I said, paste here your XMLs so people can help you out